# Unable to get Healthline search results with PHP

Tags: php, post, get, file-get-contents

I am trying to run a script that will search Healthline with a query string and determine if there are any search results, but I can't get the contents with the query string posting to the page. To search for something on their site, you go to `https://www.healthline.com/search?q1=search+string`.

Here is what I tried:

```
        $healthline_url = 'https://www.healthline.com/search';
        $search_string = 'ashwaganda';
        
        $postdata = http_build_query(
            array(
                'q1' => $search_string
            )
        );
        $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $postdata
            )
        );
        $stream = stream_context_create($opts);

        $theHtmlToParse = file_get_contents($healthline_url, false, $stream);

        print_r($theHtmlToParse);
```

I also tried to just add the query string to the url and skip the stream, amongst other variations, but I'm running out of ideas. This also didn't work:

```
        $healthline_url = 'https://www.healthline.com/search';
        $search_string = 'ashwaganda';
        
        $opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'method'=>"GET",
                'header'=>"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"
            )
        );
        $stream = stream_context_create($opts);

        $theHtmlToParse = file_get_contents($healthline_url.'&q1='.$search_string, false, $stream);

        print_r($theHtmlToParse);
```

And suggestions?

EDIT: I changed the url in case someone wants to look at the search page. Also fixed the query string. Still doesn't work.

In response to Ken Lee, I did try the following cURL script that also just returns the page without search results:

```
    $healthline_url = 'https://www.healthline.com/search?q1=ashwaganda';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $healthline_url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($data);
```

Comment: What response do you get back? `POST` != `GET`, are both methods supported? Is the cookie required?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong header with the cookie. I just fixed it. The POST option doesn't return anything. The GET option returns the search page but without the search results as if the page didn't have a query string.

Comment: `$healthline_url.'/q1='` should be `$healthline_url.'?q1='` You also should URL encode `$search_string`

Comment: Thanks, I saw that too, and fixed it, but it didn't help.

Comment: `$theHtmlToParse = file_get_contents('StaticUrlFromBrowser');` brings back the results though?

Comment: I am testing it out on a page if you want to see what it's showing. Not sure if I can share it here or if the chat option is still available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238971/discussion-between-michael-and-user3783243).

Comment: @KenLee, I added the cURL script that I have tried above, and that gives me the same results. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @KenLee, can you chat in the link in the comments above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Healthline does not load the search result directly. It has its search index stored in [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) and made extra javascript calls to retrieve the result. Therefore you cannot see the search result by `file_get_content`.

To see the search result, you need to run a browser simulator that simulates a javascript-capable browser to properly run the site page.

For PHP developers, you may try using [php-webdriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) to control browers through webdriver (e.g. Selenium, Chrome + chromedriver, Firefox + geckodriver).

**Update:** Didn't know that the target site is Healthline. Updated the answer once I found out.

Comment: I tried that, too. It just gets the page without the search results.

Comment: It depends on the actual search engine to use. It might have other mechanism that blocks your attempt. Unless we have the source code or the actual site to test with, it is hard to guess what it is.

Comment: Thank you @KoalaYeung! I appreciate you looking into it. That makes sense. I will look into this further as I've never gone that route.